# NDepend:  How to not display 'tier' assemblies in dependency graph?

Tags: ndepend, assemblies, dependencies, graph

I was able to do this in an earlier version of nDepend by going to tools->options and setting which assemblies would be part of the analysis (and ignore the rest).  The latest version of the trial version of nDepend lets me set it, but it seems to ignore the setting and always analyze all assemblies whether I want it to or not.  I tried to delete the "tier" assemblies by moving them over to the "application assemblies" list, but when I delete them out of there, they just get added back to the "tier" list, which I can't ignore.

I don't want my dependency graph to contain assemblies like "system," "system.xml," and "system.serialization!"  I want only MY assemblies in the dependency graph!  Or is that a paid-version feature now?

Is there a way to do what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3):

- If you are talking of the **live graph in the UI**, in the *Dependency Graph panel*, to remove third-party assemblies there is the menu *Reset (top-left icon) >>> Reset to application assemblies only*
- If you are talking of the **graph in the report**, just tick the box *NDepend Project Properties >>> Report >>> Assemblies Dependency Graph >>> Hide third-party assemblies*

Comment: When removing them from the project file, they automatically re-apear. And how to manually do this from the UI? Can not remove assemblies from the UI (ctrl-shift-G)